# rewrite nginx route to lowercase

Tags: nginx

What I want to achieve is to redirect all nginx routes to lowercase, like `/PATH` to `/path`. I've seen you can do it by using the perl module or lua module, but is there a way to do without those 2 and using the core module or some built-in functionality?

Thanks

**Update:**
nginx -V output:

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads
```

Comment: Reasons you can't use perl? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3666003/2774776

Comment: @JacobEvans For what I've read you need to compile nginx with the perl module because it's not built in, right?

Comment: Depends how you got nginx.

Comment: its not an option at the moment to recompile nginx. Is there another alternative?

Comment: can you include the output of `nginx -V`

Comment: updated the question with the output since it was too long @JacobEvans

Comment: ubuntu, you don't need to recompile, just `install nginx-extras`

Comment: If you really want this functionality it's best to handle it in your application's middleware. The web server is a rather unexpected place to find something like this.

Comment: nginx-extras doesn't work for me, nginx fails to load if I try to use any perl